# Location of Air France's lounges in Paris Charles de Gaulle Airport, France?

Tags: cdg, lounges, air-france

I’m transferring between two Air France flights in Paris CDG airport. There is plenty of time between flights so I plan to go to a lounge but I can’t find a map with the location of lounges, or at least a description where they are (i.e. "near the gate XYZ").

Can somebody explain (or post a map) where are AF lounges in Terminal 2F and E (gates K or L)?

Comment: Thanks JoErNanO for pointing out location on AF lounges on terminal 2F.

Comment: **Do you know where 3 lounges within Terminal 2E are located? They are supposed to be somewhere on Terminal 2E Piers/Halls K, L and M. I’m guessing every pier/hall has its own lounge somewhere within the building (K, L, and M are 3 separate buildings belonging to terminal 2F) but they are not marked on any map I could find.**

Answer (score 4):

### Air France Lounge Location

[The Air France webpage on lounges](http://www.airfrance.fr/FR/en/common/guidevoyageur/aeroport/salon_monde_airfrance.htm) has a pretty detailed description of lounges in Terminals 2E:

[image: 2E Terminal Lounges]

and 2F:

[image: 2F Terminal Lounges]

More details can also be found on [the Easy CDG website (in French)](http://easycdg.com/airport-guide/airline-lounges-paris-cdg/air-france-lounges/).

[Lounge Index also has a list of lounges at CDG](http://loungeindex.com/Europe/France/CDG/), with a description of their location. According to this website, there are two Air France lounges at CDG, [one at Gate F41-56](http://loungeindex.com/Europe/France/CDG/Air%20France%20Lounge%20CDG%202F%20-%20F41/index.htm), and [another at Gate F21-36](http://loungeindex.com/Europe/France/CDG/Air%20France%20Lounge%20CDG%202F%20-%20F21/index.htm). [Their webpage on the lounge at Terminal 2E](http://loungeindex.com/Europe/France/CDG/Air%20France%20Salon%202E/index.htm) doesn't say where it is nor how to reach it. I wish I could quote the location description from the website, but they blocked highlighting and right-clicking (geniuses).

### CDG Maps

CDG Terminal maps can be found on the [dedicated webpage of the airport website](http://www.aeroportsdeparis.fr/en/passengers/access/paris-charles-de-gaulle/terminals-map). The [Terminal 2E map can be found here](http://www.aeroportsdeparis.fr/docs/default-source/passager-fichiers/acces/plan-t2e.pdf?sfvrsn=10), whilst [the Terminal 2F can be found here](http://www.aeroportsdeparis.fr/docs/default-source/passager-fichiers/acces/plan-t2f.pdf?sfvrsn=14). If you cross-reference the text description above with the maps, you should easily manage to find the lounges. Moreover, the Terminal 2F map actually shows the position of an Air France lounge:

[image: 2F Air France Lounge]

Comment: I've seen both pages before posting this. They don't have say anything about **where the lounge are _within_ the terminal**. That’s why i decided to ask here. And judging by the terminal maps walking from end of one pier of terminal 2F to end of another pier could take a while.

Comment: @paris-cdg Check out my update. P.S. [Your comment just cost me a hat.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271127/288404) :)

Comment: Thanks for the map. This big fat arrow is exactly what i was looking for. However if i see correctly there is also something near F25 (brown 30).  Can you also post the map for 2E Gates K and 2E gates L? I can't find even a hint where lounge should be on 2E map, but according to the list there are 3 of them. I guess map of 2E is older than lounges so they were not included in the map.

Comment: @paris-cdg You are right. Updated. :)

Answer (score 2):

The Air France Lounges in CDG T2 terminal E gates L (first satellite) is on the upper level of the central part of the building, where security and access to the light rail transfer shuttle is.

When coming out of security, you'll have elevators on either side to get you to them.

[image: Access to Air France Lounges in CDG Terminal 2E, gates L]

Even though this is supposed to be one of Air France's flagship lounges, don't expect anything like Singapore Airlines, Cathay Pacific or even British Airways Lounges in their respective main hubs.

Not quite sure where the lounges are for the K and M gates. For M gates, I would expect a similar location in the central part of the building, though I can't confirm it.

Answer (score 2):

JAL provides the best map, only one listed in hall K though:

https://www.jal.co.jp/en/inter/airport/cdg/info/

[image]